# How to validate the xml content against xsd some attributes to search space exist in value

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

Below is my xml

```
<root>
<word>
 <string ID="S1" CONTENT="50 00"/>
</word>
</root>
```

I need to validate the **CONTENT** inside space should not come, If it comes It should through the error.

Any pattern match can we use in XSD. Any reference please.

Here is the XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="word"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="word">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="string">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="CONTENT" use="required">
        <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="^\s*\S+\s*"></xs:pattern>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
      <xs:attribute name="ID" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Thanks Advance...
Umesh

Comment: Where is the XSD for your XML? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry Above i have posted...

Comment: I didn't understand the problem. Is the sample XML one which should cause an error? Or is it a valid one? Do you want *no* spaces in `CONTENT`? If that's the case you could use a simple type like `xs:number` or `xs:NMTOKEN`. Please describe your problem better (possibly showing cases that are valid and cases that are not valid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of the patterns `\S*`, `[^\s]*` should do fine for you.  You don't need, and should not supply, `^` and `$` to anchor the regular expression; XSD regular expressions are always anchored, that is to say they must always describe the entire string.  You can use the whitespace facet to collapse space before pattern matching, if you want to allow leading and trailing whitespace, or you can use the pattern `\s*\S*\s*`.